# Login script gives access to wrong account sometimes

Tags: php, authentication

I have the following Registration code:

```
//Register user
if (isset($_POST['btnRegister'])) {

    //Check if mail already exists
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM user_account WHERE email=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email_);
    $email_ = $_POST['email'];
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($email);
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "Dit account bestaat al";
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        $insert_id = 0;

        //Add to Database
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user_account (firstname, lastname, email, password, address, tel) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $firstname_, $lastname_, $email_, $password_, $address_, $tel_);
        $firstname_ = $_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname_ = $_POST['lastname'];
        $email_ = $_POST['email'];
        $password_ = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $address_ = $_POST['address'];
        $tel_ = $_POST['tel'];
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
           //Send mail

        }
        $insert_id = $stmt->insert_id;
        $stmt->close();

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $insert_id;
    }
}
```

And the following Login code:

```
//Login user
    if (isset($_POST['btnLogin'])) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ID, password FROM user_account WHERE email=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email_);
        $email_ = $_POST['email'];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($ID, $password);
        $stmt->fetch();

        if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $ID;
            header("Location: /account/");
        } else {
            header("Location: /index#login-of-registreer");
        }
    }
```

Database table:

```
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID         | bigint unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstname  | varchar(250)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastname   | varchar(250)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email      | varchar(250)    | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| tel        | varchar(16)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(250)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address    | varchar(250)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| postalcode | varchar(4)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This code works perfectly in 99.9% of the cases. When entering the wrong mail/password you don't get access, and when entering a correct combination you get nicely redirected to your personal account space.
email is unique in the database table.

However, I have had one or two reports of a very strange case. It was of a user who tried to login, and got access to a very random user account.
Seems like the `$_SESSION['user_id']` got assigned a random value.

What am I doing wrong in my code that this behaviour exists in some very rare cases? I am not able to reproduce it in any way.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the user(s) being set to the same incorrect account? Is the behavior consistent for the reporting user(s)?

Comment: No; they were redirected to two different accounts. The behavior was also not consistent at all. One got redirected to the wrong account directly after registration (I guess) and the other one just entered totally wrong credentials (a mail and password totally not existing in the database). The first one, directly after the registration,  is rather vague though and an unclear report.